# What tense do we use with "Thought"

Tags: tense

I thought you were one of those people who **like** listening to this kind of music.

I thought you were one of those people who **liked** listening to this kind of music.

Are both the sentences grammatically correct, and do they mean the same thing?

Comment: I think it depends on the current status of "you"; like would imply he still likes that. "liked" means he no longer likes that. I think that is a question about back-shifting.

Comment: Are both the sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: This follows the rules for reported or indirect speech. With *thought*, you are "reporting" your own speech to yourself.

Comment: The relative clause in your second example has backshifted tense (from present to past), but it does not contain reported speech. "Thought" is a modal preterite and doesn't refer to past time at all; but it still provides a context in which backshift can take place.